# Getting the error of OutofGas evm

Tags: evm

I've ensured EVM compatibility in my substrate-chain. The default contracts from Remix, such as storage, ballot, and owner are working correctly. However, when I deploy alternative contracts like ERC-721, they deploy successfully. Yet, when I attempt to call any function of these contracts, an Out-of-Gas error is displayed in the blockchain events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our team recently submitted two fixes about the `OutofGas`:

- https://github.com/polkadot-evm/frontier/pull/1239
- https://github.com/polkadot-evm/frontier/pull/1257

Check out the latest version of Frontier.